# Reading error of console using an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, console

I am trying to read the error output from a console using a plugin. This is the piece of code I am running for that

```
ProcessConsole console =null;
 try
 {
   ProcessConsole processconsole = (ProcessConsole) console;
   processconsole.getProcess().getStreamsProxy().getErrorStreamMonitor().addListener(new IStreamListener() {
   public void streamAppended(String text, IStreamMonitor monitor) {
        System.out.println("--" + text + "--");
        question = text;    
   }
 });
     return;
   }
catch(Exception e1)
{
  System.out.println("-- No text to be displayed --");
  console =null;
}
```

This piece of code is called when I click a button provided that there are already error messages in the console. But after clicking the button it always prints '-- No text to be displayed --' in the plugin console (I am running the plugin locally by creating a new Eclipse instance when I run it) i.e it always goes to the catch block. Is there anyway to get the error content of the console and store it in the question variable using this method or is there some other way?

Comment: There are various console extension points that can listen for console output - such as `org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleLineTrackers` and `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners`

Comment: Is there any example of how to use this? I went through the documentation but I didn't understand much.